# Problem with Sundaram book question 50

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I've tried every theorem from the book but I couldn't answer the following question:
Let f: $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function which satisfies:
$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$  Show that if $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$, then its continuous at every point of $\mathbb{R}$. Also show that if $f$ vanishes at a single point of $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ vanishes at every point of $\mathbb{R}$.
Any tips, clues of how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: What is meant by "vanishes at a single point of $\mathbb R$"?

Answer (score 1):

Consider any $x_0\neq 0$ in $\mathbb R$. Setting $h = x-x_0$, we take:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x) \begin{array}[t]{l}= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} f(x_0 + h) =\lim\limits_{h\to 0} [f(x_0) \cdot f(h) ]= f(x_0) \cdot \lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(h) \\[2ex]= f(x_0) \cdot f(0) = f(x_0 + 0 ) = f(x_0).
\end{array}$$

Thus, $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$ for any $x_0 \in \mathbb R^*$, thus $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

---

Take an $x_1 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_1) = 0$.

Then: $$f(x_1 + y ) = f(x_1) \cdot f(y) = 0 \cdot f(y) =0,\quad \forall y\in \mathbb R.$$

Thus, $f(x_1 + y) = f(z) =0, \forall z\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $f(0) = a$. Then $f(x) = f(x+0) = f(x)f(0) = af(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. What can you conclude about $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $c$ be some constant.

Since $f(c+x)=f(c)f(x)$ we have:

$f$ is continuous at $x=0\implies f(x+c)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Next to that the following statements are equivalent:

- the function prescribed by $x\mapsto f(c+x)$ is equivalent at $x=0$
- the function prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$ is equivalent at $x=c$

This for every constant $c$.